# Calculating fluid volume using arduino sensors

Tags: sensors

I would like to measure liquid sealant volume inside bike tires, using sensor located between rim beads.
I guess it would by possible, by using ToF sensor, that would measure distance between rim and fluid surface.
[image: yellow - fluid itself]
Yellow - fluid itself
Than I would like to calculate fluid volume by using a formula for torus ?cap?

In another words: drained fluid would look like this cut section (not to scale):
[image]
Is there any mathematical formula to calculate volume of such "cap", based on its height and two torus radiuses? I only found formula for "ball cap" volume...

Or maybe there is better approach to measure volume, and I am doing it wrong?

Comment: There certainly is a formula to calculate that torus cap volume, though this is Arduino SE and not Mathematical SE, thus off topic. How do you plan to get any kind of sensor inside the inner tube of the tire? You normally cannot cut them open and seal them again to still hold the typical 3 bar pressure

Comment: you could use a weigh scale to determine the mount of fluid inside the inner tube

Comment: Your question seems like about geometry. You should try another channel, not Arduino maybe.

Comment: How are you at integrals?

Comment: @chrisl - there are new bikes with tubeless tires and many users are converting to tubelesss. That's the only possibility for this type of measurement. I'm going to try another channel.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then it may be easier to make a capacitive sensor. Found [this thread](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=75402.0) with a quick google  but there are certainly better resources, when you search for them

Comment: Thanks I would consider it.

Comment: [This article](https://mathhelpforum.com/threads/volume-of-toroidal-section.61981/) doesn't have the answer, but it may be of some help in formulating an approach.

Comment: It may be helpful for someone: I haven't found any formula for torus cap yet. Only for ellipsoid cap, there: https://www.vcalc.com/equation/?uuid=7cbe5611-1e51-11e8-abb7-bc764e2038f2

Comment: If you need a ''small cap" compared to the rest of figure you can treat this cap as ellipsoid cap. Just tweak ellipsoid values, so that the curves matches circle of torus cross section in area I'm interested in.